# jquery: my X and Y cordinates for my jquery "hover over plugin" does not work

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have a jquery plugin that creates a hover over text box for A tags.

The plugin works by extracting the text from the 'title attr' of the A tag and then placing it in a div tag ( called #hoverText). the #hoeverText div tag is 'positioned absolutely ' to be 10px from the X and Y coordinates of the A tag.

However, this portion of my code is not working and I don't know how to fix it. The hoverText div tag seems to stay at the top of the page. so, if I have an A tag at the bottom of a page, the hoverText div tag will not be visible as it's at the top of the page

I have placed a copy of my plugin at the bottom of this page and would really appreciate any advice or help.

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.hoverText= function() {

 $(this).after('<div id="hoverText"></div>' );

//  if (title != undefined || title != ''){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){

      title = $(this).attr ('title');
      $(this).attr( 'title', '');  


    }).mousemove(function(e) {


    var top= e.clientY + 10;
    var left= e.clientX + 10;

//  $('#pos').text(top + '  ' + left );

$('#hoverText').css('top', top).css('left', left ).text(title).show();
}).mouseout(function() {

    $(this).attr('title',  title );
    $('#hoverText').hide(); 

    });



}
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Instead of using absolute positioning, i would just add the div after the A and then position the div using margin or padding. Absolute positioning means the item will go to position itself according to the parent item (when given a top, left, right, bottom). If you really want to stick with the top and left approach, you could try relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Variables title, top and left must be declared as global variables so they can be used in every function.

Comment: hi. i preume that the way to make a global variable is to simply remove the word "var" from the statment. eg instead of var  top= e.clientY + 10; i will declar it as follows:   top= e.clientY + 10;. Can you please confirm whether this is the correct approach to make a global variable. i did try this but it made no diffrence to the script

Comment: You have to declare variables title, top and left right after function declaration, so like this:

$.fn.hoverText= function() {
   var title, top, left; .....